# Update count for external link

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app for storing my bookmarks. To do that there is a `Links` collection with a `count` attribute. Every time I click the bookmark, the external site must be visited, but also the `count` must be increased with 1, so I can sort the bookmarks with the most visited at the top.

So now I have a link with the info in it:

```
<a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">{{title}}</a>
```

Should I use a template instead, update the count and do a `Router.go` to the external site?

Comment: You could use a Template.events function on 'click a', send the count to your page and then use `window.open(url,'_blank');` to go to the new page.

Comment: OK, that works. Is it also the best "Meteor like" solution to use a good old ``window.open``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little modification:

```
<a href="{{url}}" target="_blank" class="tracked">{{title}}</a>
```

Then you could use:

```
Template.body.events({
    'click a.tracked' : function(e) {
        var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
        ClickedLinks.insert({href: href, when: new Date()});        
    }
});
```

Where `ClickedLinks` is a collection. The main idea is that we track *all* click events on meteor `body` as a catch-all since everything is rendered in the `body` anyway even if it's in another template.. everything still winds up getting rendered there. Then we try to depend on events propagation to do our magic.

Here it is in action:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/Wtz6autqgCDEaJTLw/Leaderboard